# Is the code for dilation can be use in erosion to get the required result?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The output for applying erosion by using built-in function `cv2.erode()` doesn't match the output where without OpenCV built-in function for erosion.  And my question is "Is the code for Dilation from scratch(mean without using `cv2.dilate()`) is same for erosion ? "

```
#Code for Erosion from scratch :

import cv2
import numpy as np
from dataPath import DATA_PATH
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6.0, 6.0)
matplotlib.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

im = np.zeros((10,10),dtype='uint8')

im[0,1] = 1
im[-1,0]= 1
im[-2,-1]=1
im[2,2] = 1
im[5:8,5:8] = 1

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))

ksize = element.shape[0]
height,width = im.shape[:2]

border = ksize//2
# Create a padded image with zeros padding
#paddedIm = np.zeros((height + border*2, width + border*2))
paddedIm = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = 1)
for h_i in range(border, height+border):
    for w_i in range(border,width+border):
        # When you find a white pixel
        if im[h_i-border,w_i-border]:
            print("White Pixel Found @ {},{}".format(h_i,w_i))

            paddedIm[ h_i - border : (h_i + border)+1, w_i - border : (w_i + border)+1] = \
                cv2.bitwise_and(paddedIm[ h_i - border : (h_i + border)+1, w_i - border : (w_i + border)+1],element)

            # Print the intermediate result
            print(paddedIm)
            plt.imshow(paddedIm);plt.show()

erodedImage = paddedIm[border:border+height,border:border+width]
plt.imshow(erodedImage)
```

Input image :
[Image for erosion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGj8.jpg)

Output image using `cv2.erode()`(Expected Output Image):
[Final image from using cv2.erode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0qVQ.jpg)

Output image without using inbuilt function for erosion (Output Image that I get):
[Output Image without using cv2.erode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A1Gu.jpg)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The code for erosion is not the same as for dilation, because these are two different operations. Where you implemented dilation with a logical OR, erosion would be implemented with AND. Alternatively, one can invert the input image, apply the dilation, and invert the result to form an erosion.

Comment: Sir @CrisLuengo , I have change `cv2.bitwise_and()` but the output acquired using `cv2.erode()` is not same as the output that acquired from code for erosion from scratch.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have edit my question and given the input image, expected output image and the output image that I get . Reply ASAP sir.

Comment: Sir @CrisLuengo , Can you help me please in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways that you can implement the binary dilation and erosion.

The code you have for the dilation uses the "stamping" method, where for each foreground pixel you stamp the structuring element (i.e. set to foreground each pixel covered by the structuring element centered on the given pixel).

The erosion counterpart to this algorithm is to stamp the structuring element for each background pixel: for each **background** pixel, set to **background** each pixel covered by the structuring element centered on the given pixel.

Thus, `if im[h_i-border,w_i-border]:` becomes `if not im[h_i-border,w_i-border]:`, and `paddedIm[...] = cv2.bitwise_or(paddedIm[...],element)` becomes `paddedIm[...] = cv2.bitwise_and(paddedIm[...],~element)`. (You could pre-compute `~element` for efficiency.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir.